# Router changing default gateway when creating a DNS

Tags: dns, router, gateway, proxmox

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and my router is TP-Link AXE-5400. I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux for that matter, but I managed to make some VM via Proxmox. Cloud server, gaming server, Plex and so on. I was tired to typing all the IP addresses and wanted to create a VM that runs as a DNS. When everything was done my router just went bananas and changed the gateway which made me lose contact with Proxmox and all my VM. After a lot work trying to change back the gateway which it didn't let me until I blocked the connection in the router to that specific VM and then I renewed the IP on Proxmox and finally got a connection again.

Since I was sitting for hours to make that work, I gave up and purged the VM. Obviously I'm going to try again tomorrow. My goal is that my router is going to use my DNS as primary DNS, but how do I avoid that happening again? Even though my domain got resolved and the server said everything was OK, I don't understand how it worked as a DNS since I didn't type a real DNS like Google or Cloudflare in any configuration files.

Does anyone have any suggestions for round two? I want to add that I removed the DNS server from my router and put in my new one which made it go even more crazy. I tried to make the DNS with bind9.

Comment: Please comment if you think F.Hasangjekaj needs to provide any more information in addition to the preliminary de-obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix try to get the DNS server working using Cloudfare which has an IP of 1.1.1.1 In Ubuntu just type in 1.1.1.1 in Settings app -> *Network* -> *Details* tab -> DNS to set Cloudfare as the default DNS. This will allow you to isolate the issue of the router going haywire when you attempt to set up your own DNS server.

Once you have Cloudflare's DNS working in Ubuntu, you can set up your own DNS server using bind9.

1. Run the following command to install bind9:

   ```
   sudo apt install bind9 bind9utils
   ```
2. Configure bind9 by editing the main configuration file for bind9 which is located at `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`. Make the following changes:

   ```
   listen-on-port 53 { any; };
   allow-query { any; };
   zone "example.com" IN {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
   };
   ```
3. Replace `example.com` with your actual domain name. Create a zone file named `/etc/bind/db.example.com` and add the following content:

   ```
   $TTL 3600
   example.com IN SOA ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
       2023120500 ; Serial
       3600 ; Refresh
       1800 ; Retry
       604800 ; Expire
       86400 ; Minimum
   )

   NS ns1.example.com.
   NS ns2.example.com.

   ; A record for your server
   example.com IN A 192.168.1.11
   ```
4. Run `sudo systemctl restart bind9` to restart bind9 and apply the new configuration:
5. In your router's settings, set the primary DNS server to the IP address of your DNS server (In this example it's 192.168.1.11).